# Item.Read does not work according to any of the provided docs

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb

I have gone through all the types of documentation provided about the CosmosDB Read Item method. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
const item = container.item(id, undefined);
console.log("Read item '" + item.id + "'");
const { resource: readDoc } = await item.read();
console.log("item with id found: '", readDoc);
```

The ID I pass is '1' and there is a record with id '1' in the collection.
It always return as undefined. Anybody already know how this works?

Here are the docs which I referred. (Read an item by ID : Item.read)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-samples

Comment: Run this code `const { statusCode } = await item.read();console.log("response status code: '", statusCode);` , does it return '404'?

Comment: Yes. it returns 404.. but the id is '1' and there is a record likewise on the collection with the id '1'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you pass the wrong key to `item("id","key")`. When you pass `undifined` as key of this method, it means you don't define partition key value of document which id is '1' like this screenshot.
[image]

I guess your document which id is '1' has partition key value, so cosmos DB can't find the document which id is '1' and doesn't have partition key value. If so, you need to pass your partition key value to `item("id","key")`.

For example, I have a document like below, my code should be like this:

```
const item = container.item("1", "dog");
console.log("Read item '" + item.id + "'");
const { resource: readDoc } = await item.read();
console.log("item with id found: '", readDoc);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I also tried with the partition key it didnt work for some reason. but now it works!

Comment: I have seen documentations and examples that takes only one parameter for the container.item() and the requestoptions with partitionkey property as parameter for the read() method. That did not work, but passing the partitionKey as the second parameter to the item() method works. Microsoft documentations are really unreliable and inconsistent and unintuitive. It is never to guess how they might have done something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Azure documentation is wrong (or at least incredibly confusing).

The two strings need to be the same.

e.g.

Cosmos DB Entry:

```
{ "id": "123456", "name": "John Smith" }
```

Partition Key: /id

```
const { resource } = await container
  .item("123456", "123456")
  .read();
```

or

```
const { resource } = await container
      .item("123456", "123456")
      .delete();
```

Hope that helps.